# Two formulas into one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am a novice user and have a question to calculate the days between two network days. I would like to have a result, if one cell does not have a date, a result would be "0." based on network days.

I have a formula =IF(H12="","", NETWORKDAYS(H12-B1)), but it does not work. I feel idiot.
Thank you for your time and help!

Respectfully,

Josh

Comment: what do you mean it does not work? what is in your cell? you say you want to see "0." but your formula says to return an empty string if H12 is empty. could you clarify please.

Comment: Hello Zena, thank you for your time. I guess it should be H12=0 instead of "". Sorry for the confusion. H12=(assigned date), B1=(today's date). If there is no assigned date, cell H13 will be "0." I would like to count only network days between today's date and the assigned date. I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: makes sense what you want, but you did not tell us what is not working.

Comment: When I added my above formula, I received the message saying that you've entered too few arguments. I guess I don't know what I am doing here. If H12 (no assigned date), result will be "0." If H12 has the date, H13 will show the result of days based on network days from H12-B1. I hope it answered your question. Thank you again!

Comment: Sample data would be helpful. Your formula currently has IF(condition, true). You are missing the "false" part of the IF formula.

Comment: Thanks Isolated!

Answer (score 0):

`NETWORKDAYS()` requires its parameters be shown differently than you are trying to enter them.

You need at least two items in the `()`'s:  the start date (B1, presumably), and the end date (H12) AND they need a comma between them:

```
=IF(H12="","",NETWORKDAYS(B1,H12))
```

By doing the obvious subtraction, you are actually giving it just ONE value, which it sees as the start date, and not giving it anything else, hence the "too few arguments" problem.

That's all you need to do to fix it! It's great otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Jeorje!